# Interpolation of two Excel sheets using Python to match timestamp

Tags: python, excel, matlab, dataset, interpolation

I have been recently started with Python and need to interpolate two sheets using Python. I am having trouble wrapping my head around this.

One sheet **Boston_Air_Us** contains hourly data recorded at different times/day while the other **GEMS_AOD_Boston** contains per day data of air pollutants (PM 2.5).

Both sheets have two columns (ScanTime, Pollutant_Concentration)
How do I go about matching data in minutes between two sheets while performing Interpolation?

Is this code good to go? It's not working for me.

```
`import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# Load the Excel sheets into pandas DataFrames
df_random_mins = pd.read_excel('Boston_Air_Us.xlsx')
df_every_hour = pd.read_excel('GEMS_AOD_Boston.xlsx')

# Perform interpolation
interpolated_concentration = interp1d(df_every_hour['Time'], df_every_hour['Concentration'])

# Extract interpolated concentrations for matching minutes
matched_concentrations = interpolated_concentration(df_random_mins['Time'])

# Add interpolated concentrations to the random minutes DataFrame
df_random_mins['Interpolated_Concentration'] = matched_concentrations

# Save the updated DataFrame to a new Excel file
df_random_mins.to_excel('interpolated_data.xlsx', index=False)`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem with sorting the timestamps of the two Excel. Try to add a sort before interpolation

```
df_random_mins = df_random_mins.sort_values(by='Time')
df_every_hour = df_every_hour.sort_values(by='Time')
```